# Can an entangled state in general be created by destructive interference in some subspace?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

For instance, if we have a general two-qubit state $$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle+e^{i\varphi_a}|1\rangle)\otimes(|0\rangle+e^{i\varphi_b}|1\rangle)=\frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle+e^{i\varphi_b}|01\rangle+e^{i\varphi_a}|10\rangle+e^{i(\varphi_a+\varphi_b)}|11\rangle,$$ is there a way to create a Bell state simply by arranging for the states $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$ to destructively interfere with one another so that those states are never observed? This seems exactly like the sort of thing that happens in certain processes in particle physics where two pathways/histories for a particle decay process destructively interfere with one another so neither history is ever actually observed.

If this simple case is possible, is it then possible in general to arrange *any* arbitrary entangled state of $N$ qubits by taking a state like $$|\psi\rangle=\prod_{j=1}^{N}(a_j|0\rangle_j+|1\rangle)=\sum_{(q_0,q_1,q_2,...q_N)=(0,0,0,...,0)}^{(1,1,1,...,1)}|q_0,q_1,q_2,...,q_N\rangle$$ and arranging for, say, all the states where more than one $q_j$ is in state $|1\rangle$ to destructively interfere with one another so the state becomes the entangled state $$|\psi\rangle=|10000...\rangle+|01000...\rangle+|00100...\rangle+...|00000...1\rangle~?$$

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "pathways/history". Quanta don't have a path or a history. They are not small things that move through space. We can prepare an ensemble of a system in one particular state, then let it evolve in time and then perform a measurement on it. In high energy physics the preparation is a superposition of plane waves (with different momenta) from infinity and the measurement is a scattering function at infinity. The only outcomes that can never be observed are those that are forbidden by symmetries/conservation laws.

Comment: "For instance, if we have a general two-qubit state..." This is not a general two-qubit state. It is not even a direct product of two general one-qubit states. The general one-qubit state looks like $\cos(\theta/2)|0\rangle + \sin(\theta/2)e^{i\phi}|1\rangle$. I think you mean to say something like: "For instance, if we have a direct product state of the form..."

Comment: You might find more receptive answerers here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

For distinguishable spins, $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$ are two orthogonal vectors of Hilbert space. Therefore, they cannot interfere with each other. Also, a tensor product of states belonging to different subsystems is always separable (and never entangled) independently of the phases $\phi_a$, $\phi_b$ (or the coefficients $a_j$).